# Unity DLL File Load Error

Tags: visual-studio-2013, dll, unity-container

When I attempt to run my project, it only works if Visual Studio has been set up first.

```
Execute Project -> Load Dll -> if(Setup Visual Studio) -> Success
```

But

```
Execute Project -> Load Dll -> if(Not Setup Visual Studio) -> Fail
```

Why is that happening, and how can I fix it?

Comment: Any erro log? I suspect that `Visual Studio` has the `dll`s you need.

Comment: Oh, i'm Sorry that late Answer ㅠㅠ
what is the visual studio dlls ??